# Error when trying to uninstall/reinstall git

Tags: apt, dpkg, uninstall, git

I have tried to reinstall git after having errors with pulling an update from github. I've found that there is an error with libc-bin. Can anyone give me pointers here? Thanks in advance, the whole output from install git command is below.

```
sudo apt install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  git-daemon-run | git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-el git-email git-gui gitk gitweb git-cvs git-mediawiki git-svn
The following packages will be upgraded:
  git
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 103 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/4554 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Aborted (core dumped)
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib' given more than once
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot:
        libfakeroot-0.so -> libfakeroot-tcp.so
/usr/lib/wsl/lib:
/usr/local/lib:
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
Aborted (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--configure):
 installed libc-bin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 134
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc-bin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Can you try running `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/libc-bin* ~/` and `sudo apt update && sudo apt --fix-broken install && sudo apt install libc-bin && sudo apt install git` and check back. Also [edit] to include the output of `cat /etc/*release`.

Comment: please update your question with output of this `uname -m && uname -r && cat /etc/*release`  so we know the OS you are on

Comment: ...  also its interesting to see its looking for things in `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`  can you show contents of that dir as you have installed something(s) which is making the install look there instead of the normal `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Comment: ``` uname -m && uname -r && cat /etc/*release
x86_64
4.4.0-19041-Microsoft
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal ```

Comment: The two commands by "someone" appear to have worked!

Comment: please do! I'll approve it afterwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, start by removing the post-installation files of `libc-bin` because maybe they are corrupted.

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/libc-bin* ~/
```

After that reinstall `libc-bin` and `git`:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt --fix-broken install && sudo apt install libc-bin && sudo apt install git
```

Feel free to ask me anything in the comments.